# Javascript React Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, checkbox

I am trying to have a checkbox that change a className of another tag dynamically.
There is my code :

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
class Task extends Component {
  state = {
    task: "DevApp",
  };

  isChecked = () => {
    console.log("True");
    return true;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <span className="bg-warning">{this.state.task}</span>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" />
        </label>
        <span className={this.getClassBadge()}>Done</span>]
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  getClassBadge() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
    if (x) {
      return "badge m-2 bg-warning";
    } else {
      return "badge m-2 bg-primnary";
    }
  }
}

export default Task;
```

And i get
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'checked')`

I've tried this way :

```
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <span className="bg-warning">{this.state.task}</span>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" />
        </label>
        <span className={this.getClassBadge()}>Done</span>]
      </React.Fragment>
      <script>
        getClassBadge() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
          if (x) {
            return "badge m-2 bg-warning";
          } else {
            return "badge m-2 bg-primnary";
          }
        }
      </script>
    );
  }
```

but everything is underlined in red.
I would like to have a checkbox and if the checkbox is checked the next span's className will change to have a cool effect.
Can someone please help me?
I am sorry if it is very basic but i am only starting out :)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I mean no offense, but you may want to take some time to go through some tutorials for React to get a better understanding of the workflow.  _Generally_ speaking, you shouldn't be doing any direct DOM querying or manipulation when using React-- if you see `document.getElementById` or the like that's a good indication that you are perhaps following an antipattern.  The idea with React (and most MV* libraries) is that you have a data model, and you wire a UI to that data model, and from there you simply update the data model and the UI updates accordingly.

Comment: I would recommend you go through some actual react codes containing checkbox. Because this is not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

The `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'checked')` comes because when you first render, your checkbox with that id isn't mounted to the DOM yet. Because of that the `document.getElementById("myCheck")` returns null.

Most of the time with React you shouldn't use the document object's functions.

You should instead use React's state. Since you're using a class component, you can use this.state to have a property the value of which tells whether the checkbox is checked or not. The checkbox needs a change handler, something like

`<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onChange={(state) => this.setState({isChecked: !state.isChecked})} />`

Then in `getClassBadge`, simply check for the state:

```
return this.state.isChecked
  ? "badge m-2 bg-warning"
  : "badge m-2 bg-primnary"
```